# sql trimming function

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I have a table called transactions which has a column `Customer_Transactions_ID`

Now the values in this column vary in the below

```
AB_EL_205_72330_H

AB_EL_820_23066_E_N

AB_EL_820_23066
```

I want to trim all the values that start with "AB_EL" to make them from

```
AB_EL_820_23066_E_N (or whatever variation of the above) to
AB_EL_820_23066
```

So basically no *E* or *H* after the id's

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the data properly

Comment: Also, tell us your sql language. Add its tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Be sure to add some example data and your table structure as well as the expected output. Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Comment: Are `_H` and `_E_N` the only two endings which would ever appear?

Comment: No unfortunately there are other variations like 

EGGWGR0100448120161

_E_N

_E (2)

and even some texts in this particular column. 

But I just want to trim all values beginning with AB_EL and from those ones remove all the "_E" or "_H" from those

Comment: You re-itterate that you want to remove `_E` and `_H` from the tail of your strings, but your example also removes `_N`.  You should update your question with the ***full*** and ***exact*** requirements...

Answer (score 1):

This will give your values truncated until the last ocurrence of a number.

```
SELECT
    Original = T.Customer_Transactions_ID,
    Truncated = SUBSTRING(
        T.Customer_Transactions_ID,
        1,
        LEN(T.Customer_Transactions_ID) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(T.Customer_Transactions_ID)) + 1)
FROM
    Transactions AS T
```

Comment: That's amazing!

Everything works except for those values with ids like the below:

CT_ELFS_820_00695_E_N (2)

But everything else works perfectly!!!!

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your requirement correctly.if text starts with ab_el then trim _e,_l from the text.

```
DECLARE @txt VARCHAR(100)= 'aqb_el_205_72330_h';
```

SELECT ISNULL('ab_el'+CASE
           WHEN @txt LIKE 'ab_el%'
           THEN replace(replace(REPLACE(@txt,'ab_el',''), '_e', ''), '_h', '')
       END,@txt);

Comment: This will replace the "_e" at the beginning also, not just at the end.

Comment: @EzLo, thanks for the nice observation. I have changed the code now which replaces only at the  end